# Get list of specific FTP files

Tags: uipath

I’m trying to get a specific listing of files within a FTP session with the ultimate goal of downloading the newest file.

How can I incorporate a Directory.GetFile within the FTP Enumerate Objects activity? Or is there a different way to accomplish this goal?

The default output variable is System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable. When I use the directory.getfiles, I get an error that UI Path could not find part of the path. In my variable I use “/testing/rpa” for the FTP path and in the activity it is changed to “c:\testing\rpa”

Thanks in advance,
Brad

Answer (score 0):

I ran into issues with not including full path with other activities as well. You will need to use the full path to the directory or UIPath will automatically append your partial path. I cannot find anything in the UIPath [activities documentation](https://activities.uipath.com/docs/) on directory.GetFiles, but everywhere else in the documentation where there is a path property, it asks for the "full path":

[image: full path documentation]

Watch [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bqpfzaE5Acc) as a reference for enumerating a file directory. I am sure you have everything correct except for including the full path, but here is a snap of what iterating files in a directory might look like in UI Studio.

[image: enumerate files]